# How to write an array to a json file in C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to write a json file from C# code as following json file would look:

```
{
    "Monday": [
      {
        "class": "Example",
        "time": "09:00"
      },
      {
        "class": "Example2",
        "time": "09:50"
      }
    ],

    "Tuesday": [
      {
        "class": "Example3",
        "time": "09:00"
      },
      {
        "class": "Example4",
        "time": "09:50"
      }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT** This is the class i'm using:

```
public class Lesson {
      public string title { get; set; }
      public string timeStart { get; set; }
      public string timeEnd { get; set; }
}
```

I've found ways to write the single objects into the file, although I've found nothing about the arrays.

Excuse me in advance if the solution is obvious and I'm wasting your time, but I just recently started working with json files.

Thanks in advance,

bezunyl

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>` or paste your JSON here: [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp) and use the class model provided to serialize/deserialize the JSON.

Comment: use `Json.NET` library, it has everything you need.

Comment: your class doesn't map to your json at all.  For a helpful answer, you'll have to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. add Json.NET to your project
2. create `Dictionary<string,List<Lesson>>`
3. Call `JsonConver.SerializeObject(dict)`.

Here is an example of many possible ways how to interact with the dictionary.

```
dict["Monday"]= new List<Lesson>();
dict["Monday"].Add(new Lesson(...));

When calling SerializeObject you can specify formatting as Indented: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, Formatting.Indented);`
```